# Linkify Html text with Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to linkify an HTML code using Dart / Flutter and get the same result as a Javascript function I already use.

It is important to note that the received text can be a mixture of plain text and HTML.

Basically I would like to transform this:

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
Visit this link: http://www.link1.com<br />

And <strong>this</strong>: 
<a href="http://www.link2.com">http://www.link2.com</a>
```

Into this:

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
Visit this link: <a href="http://www.link1.com">http://www.link1.com</a><br />

And <strong>this</strong>: 
<a href="http://www.link2.com">http://www.link2.com</a>
```

I've tried this plugin, but it only works with plain text: https://github.com/blossom/linkify-dart

The javascript code below works exactly as expected

```
function linkify(text) {
        var url_pattern = /(\()((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\))|(\[)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\])|(\{)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(\})|(<|&(?:lt|#60|#x3c);)((?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+)(>|&(?:gt|#62|#x3e);)|((?:^|[^=\s'"\]])\s*['"]?|[^=\s]\s+)(\b(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]+(?:(?!&(?:gt|#0*62|#x0*3e);|&(?:amp|apos|quot|#0*3[49]|#x0*2[27]);[.!&',:?;]?(?:[^a-z0-9\-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]|$))&[a-z0-9\-._~!$'()*+,;=:\/?#[\]@%]*)*[a-z0-9\-_~$()*+=\/#[\]@%])/img;
        var url_replace = '$1$4$7$10$13<a href="$2$5$8$11$14" target="_blank">$2$5$8$11$14</a>$3$6$9$12';
        return text.replace(url_pattern, url_replace);
    }

    function _linkify_html_callback(m0, m1, m2) {
        if (m2) {
            return m2;
        }
        return linkify(m1);
    }

    /**
     * Original from https://github.com/jmrware/LinkifyURL
     */
    function linkifyHtm() {
        var text = this.replace(/&amp;apos;/g, '&#39;');
        var section_html_pattern = /([^<]+(?:(?!<a\b)<[^<]*)*|(?:(?!<a\b)<[^<]*)+)|(<a\b[^>]*>[^<]*(?:(?!<\/a\b)<[^<]*)*<\/a\s*>)/ig;
        return text.replace(section_html_pattern, _linkify_html_callback);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we are having a complicated expression, which we could start with a list of constraints before and the same after the URLs, and maybe adding them in a char class. For example, we can start with an expression such as:

```
\s+(https?.+?)(<|\s)
```

which `(https?.+?)` would capture our URLs, before that we add `\s+` boundary for instance, then after, we would be adding `(<|\s)`. We then would work on these two left and right boundaries for other cases that we might be having.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VQHxj9/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /\s+(https?.+?)(<|\s)/gm;
const str = `<h1>Hello</h1>
Visit this link: http://www.link1.com<br />
Visit this link: http://www.link1.com <br />
Visit this link: http://www.link1.com/some_other_words <br />
And <strong>this</strong>: 
<a href="http://www.link2.com">http://www.link2.com</a>`;
const subst = ` <a href="$1">$1</a>$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VQHxj9/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Emma for the help. The current solution to my problem is this:

```
_str = _str.replaceAllMapped(
      new RegExp(r'(>|\s)+(https?.+?)(<|\s)',
             multiLine: true, caseSensitive: false), (match) {
      return '${match.group(1)}<a href="${match.group(2)}">${match.group(2)}</a>${match.group(3)}';
    }
);
```

There are several issues that may still appear (characters like &, =,? In url etc ...). But that's enough for now